How to get SFML library installed correctly for MINGW
First thing is, I am a complete beginner to C++ and I'm using VSCode with MINGW. For a project I need the SFML external library installed. I'm not using Visual Studio because my PC is like 10 year old, processor is older than that, VS is obviously gonna kill my PC if I use it:(
I want SFML library installed correctly on my PC that's all, but it never happens :(
First I searched for a SFML version for my current compiler mingw13.2, but there was none, but I tried the available one, sfml for mingw 13.1, and placed all the library files in the right locations, updated all the path environment variables, but encountered a linker error, I thought it was because the version was not the right one.
Then I downloaded the source code for the library, followed the instructions on the official SFML page(https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/compile-with-cmake.php), used CMake GUI to generate the build files. Then I couldn't find any more instructions, so had to ask ChatGPT, bro told me to use cmd, use mingw32-make.exe, I did it, it gave an error at the end.
I tried two more source codes for SFML from github and tried, one failed at the cmd step, and the other worked. So used VSCode again to compile everything, but I think the source code was not the correct one, it also gave some errors.
So I installed MINGW 13.1 instead, and since SFML was available for that version, downloaded the library and placed all the files in the right locations, ran into many issues but got them fixed, and the build finished successfully. But when running it through VSCode, just nothing happens.
When double clicking on the .exe file, it gave an error,
"The procedure entry point _ZNSt15basic_streambuflcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekposESt4fposliESt13_los_Openmode could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\msys64\mingw64_13.1\bin\sfml-system-2.dll"
The thing is all the dll files are there, the versions are correct, I don't understand.
I would highly appreciate if anyone can help me out:))) I just wanted to get into making a simple game, and I am stuck on the first step of installing an external library :((

The correct (and easy) way to install everything MSYS2 related is to use their package manager pacman. This includes the compiler, any third party libraries and any additional tools that you want to use. If you haven't been using pacman up until now, start again and use it second time around. No more version conflicts, and easy updating.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78395953/15649230

Incidentally, you don't seem to be a typical beginner, but using third party libraries is not something I'd advise for a complete beginner at C++. Spend some time learning C++ on it's own first.

it seems you have in fact installed sfml using pacman, but you have another version of SFML on your system, and you are linking against a different version than the one installed by pacman .... so either uninstall the one from pacman or link against it, don't keep it lying around while you link to another version, that's why you are getting runtime errors.

Side note: VS is pretty lightweight compared to many of the common IDEs out there.

Most likely you wanted to type: pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-sfml  in a msys2 terminal to install the ucrt64 version since VSCode recommends using ucrt: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-sfml?repo=ucrt64 and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Visual Studio and/or Visual Studio Build Tools are perfectly fine even on older hardware. I have no idea where this sentiment comes from that VS is somehow to large or too heavy to be used on older hardware...
Personally, I still recommend using Visual Studio, as the provided tooling (e.g. debugging) is a superior experience compared to VS Code, especially for a beginner.
If you do want to stick to MinGW, you have multiple options to choose from:

Use MSYS2 for everything
Use MSYS2's compiler, but build SFML yourself
Use your own MinGW installation and build SFML yourself

Use MSYS2 for Everything
The comments above have already provided some help for that. Use the built-in package manager pacman to install MinGW and SFML.
pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain
pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-sfml

Build SFML Yourself
These days we recommend to use the SFML CMake Template instead of manually building and linking SFML, as it automates these steps for you. Just follow the instructions on the README.
You can pick whether you want to use the compiler provided by MSYS2 (see above) or download your own version. Personally, I highly recommend using WinLibs if you choose to use your own installation.
